# Meteor.subscribe on server side

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to create a backend service which monitors a mongodb collection for new entries. As those are being created, I wish to run processing and update them.
I thought doing so with a Meteor service/app would be a wise idea because Meteor uses 'oplog tailing' which seems ideal for this purpose (I'd rather avoid polling if possible).

As such, I figured creating a minimal server-side-only app should solve it. 
So basically, I need something along these lines:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('myCollection');
    Meteor.publish('myCollectionPub', function () {
         return MyCollection.find({ some: criteria... });
    }
    // is there such a thing?
    Meteor.serverSideSubscribe('MyCollectionPub', 
        function (newDocs) {
            // process/update newDocs
    });
}
```

According to [the Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe), I cannot use `Meteor.subscribe()` on the server (and indeed it crashes if I try).

Question is:
Are there ways of 'subscribing' to collection updates on the server?

Answer (score 2):

The [PeerLibrary server-autorun package](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-server-autorun) (along with it's dependant, [reactive-mongo](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-mongo)) will provide you with easy server-side observation of collections.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @tarmes suggestion is the collection-hooks package, however as pointed out by David Weldon, it will only trigger in instance it is run in:

https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks

```
MyCollection.after.insert(function (userId, doc) {
    // ...
});
```

If you need it to run even when another instance makes a change in the mongo database, you can observe a cursor that is returned from your collection:

```
MyCollection.find({created_at : {$gt: some_current_time}}).observe({
    added: function(item) {
        // Alert code
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if `MyCollection.after.insert` callback fires when the mongo collection updates externally? (as in, when another meteor/node instances update it?

Comment: From my understanding of how mongo works (oplog tailing and replica sets), I believe that this should work in that scenario. Another app updating mongo remotely would be the same as if you went into mongo shell and updated an item in the collection.

Comment: There are two big caveats with this answer: (1) I'm pretty sure hooks only execute on the instance they were started on - see [this issue](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks/issues/165), (2) `observe` is a great solution (I use it a lot for cases this these), however it often limits you to only listening from one server. I.e. if two servers called `observe` and they both ran their callback, would that be acceptable?

Comment: @DavidWeldon thanks for chiming in! Can you elaborate on why collection-hooks is running at the instance level but observe() is not? I will amend my answer.

Comment: You'd need to really dig into the source to figure out what's going on, but as I recall, it's event-based. It wraps each collection event in the current app instance and runs the hook for that instance accordingly. You won't find `observe` or `observeChanges` anywhere in the source. Running a `find().observe`, however, will actually continually observe the oplog for changes from any app instance.

Comment: @DavidWeldon correct me if I'm wrong, but seems like the `observe` method is the best answer as the official docs already include it http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe

Comment: @tivoni yes, I'd recommend you start with an implementation using `observe`.